# Return generic functional interface in Java 8

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming, java-8

I want to write kind of function factory. It should be a function, which is called once which different strategies as parameters. It should return a function, which selects one of this strategies dependent on the parameter, which is to be fulfilled by a predicate.
Well, better look at `condition3` for better understanding.
The problem is, that it is not compiling. I think because the compiler can't figure out, that the functional interface `H` can be realized by the implementation.
Without generics it is working fine.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Finder<T, S> {

    Stream<S> findBest (T t);

    // Valid code
    static <P, Q> Finder<P, Q> condition1 () {
        return p -> null;
    }

    // Valid code, but selects just one of the H's when the method is invoked
    static <P, Q, H extends Finder<P, Q>> H condition2 (Pair<Predicate<P>, H>... hs) {
        return hs[0].getRight ();
    }

    // Should return a method, which selects the appropiate H 
    // whenever it is invoked with an P
    // Compiler complain: 
    // The target type of this expression must be a functional interface
    static <P, Q, H extends Finder<P, Q>> H condition3 (Pair<Predicate<P>, H>... hs) {
        return p -> stream (hs).filter (pair -> pair.getLeft ().test (p))
                               .findFirst ()
                               .map (Pair::getRight)
                               .map (h -> h.findBest (p))
                               .orElseGet (Stream::empty);
    }
}
```

So what's the problem here? Can I solve it and if it's possible with Java: how?

Comment: Please provide the full compilation error message.

Comment: "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface." It is in the comment above the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the signature of your method and try to tell what the exact return type is:

```
static <P, Q, H extends Finder<P, Q>> H condition3(…
```

Lambdas can only implement an `interface` known at compile-time. But the actual type argument for `H` is not known to the compiler.

Your first method works because it returns the type `Finder<P, Q>` which the lambda can implement, your second works because it doesn’t use a lambda for implementing the return type `H extends Finder<P, Q>`.

Only your third method attempts to specify a lambda expression for a type argument `H extends Finder<P, Q>`.

---

A solution is not to give the caller the freedom to mandate a particular sub-type of `Finder` as the method’s return type:

```
static <P, Q, H extends Finder<P, Q>>
    Finder<P, Q> condition3(Pair<Predicate<P>, H>... hs) {
```

---

To illustrate what implications your original method signature has, look at the following example:

```
final class HImpl implements Finder<String,String> {
    public Stream<String> findBest(String t) {
        return null; // just for illustration, we never really use the class
    }
}
```

…

```
HImpl x=Finder.<String,String,HImpl>condition3();
```

Given your original method signature this compiles without any error. But how ought the method `condition3` provide an instance of `HImpl` here using your lambda expression?

Comment: Aren't generics resolved at compile time? I think when I use condition3() with an argument, the type of H is defined and it replaces the generic return type H at compile time with the specific type?

Comment: They are resolved at compile time but only the **caller** of method `condition3` knows the actual type arguments as every call site might use a different type for `H`. Compare with `Collections.emptyList()`: it returns a `List<T>` which might  `List<Integer>` or `List<String>` depending on how you use it. This works only because the returned list is empty as the implementation of `Collections.emptyList()` never knows the type of `T` and can’t provide real values for it.

Comment: But in `Collections.emptyList()` there are no provided type arguments. I think with `Pair<Predicate<P>, H>... hs` the type should be defined. And when I provide an argument of Type `Pair<Predicate<PImpl>, HImpl>` I would expect that the compiler knows that the return type is `HImpl`. And since `HImpl` is because of the restriction `H extends Finder<P, Q>` a functional interface, the compiler should be able to find out the type of the lambda expression as `HImpl`.

Comment: You seem to be confused about what Generics do. `H extends Finder<P, Q>` does **not** required that `H` is a functional interface. It just says that `H` must fulfill the `Finder` interface. It might be an arbitrary type extending or implementing `Finder`. It might be an interface extending `Finder` and adding more methods thus not being a functional interface. The actual type argument for `H` might be even a `final` class. See my updated answer.