# Mark generic type parameter as functional interface in Java 8

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to restrict the type parameter of a function to be a functional interface.

Something like this:

```
public static <@FunctionalInterface T extends Function<A, B>> T foo () {
    return a -> bar;
}
```

The `@FunctionalInterface` is not allowed here.

The aim is, to make it possible to return a lambda with the type of the type parameter. Since `T` can be a normal class, a return of a lambda is not allowed.

Is there a possibility to restrict the type parameter to be a functional interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already discussed on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24366220/2711488) it is *impossible* to do that. Not only annotating the type parameter but especially implementing an unknown interface via lambda expression.

When compiling your method

```
public static <@FunctionalInterface T extends Function<A, B>> T foo() {
    return a -> bar;
}
```

the compiler must produce code capable of returning an instance of the appropriate type but it doesn’t know what `T` will be as this depends on the caller of `foo()` but there is no connection between compiling `foo()` and compiling the caller of `foo()`. The latter might happen years later on the other side of the our planet.

Maybe you are not aware of [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). There will be only one compiled version of your method `foo()` but it has to fulfill the generic contract of returning an instance of the appropriate type. *Without knowing what* `T` *is*.

This works when returning an existing instance like when returning an element of a collection or one of the values passed as parameters. But generic methods are unable to return new instances of a type parameter. Not using `new` and neither using a lambda expression.

---

Note that it is still possible to have sub-interface implementations of the desired function if you let the caller which knows the type perform the “up-level” operation. Suppose the you have a Generic factory method like:

```
public static <A,B> Function<A,B> getter(Map<?, ? extends B> map) {
    return a->map.get(a);
}
```

This code works with the unknown types `A` and `B` and the unknown parametrization of `Map` because the only constraint is the method `Map.get` accepts instances of `A` which it does as it accepts *anything* and returns an instance of `B` which it does as any type `? extends B` will be assignable to `B`.

Now, if your caller has an arbitrary sub-type of `Function`, `X`, e.g.

```
interface X extends Function<String, Integer> {}
```

it can use your factory method to produce an instance of `X` which *decorates* the function, like:

```
Map<String, Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
X x=getter(map)::apply;
x.apply("foo");
```

Here, the constraint on `X` being a *functional interface* is checked on the caller site.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: You are right, if you do not construct it, it will work. In your answer it doesn’t work because the `Map` type does not match the `Function`’s return type, i.e. `Map` maps to `Integer` and your `Function` shall return `R extends Integer` which makes not much sense as `Integer` is `final` but the compiler is still picky about this, and insists on `Integer` not being convertible to `R extends Integer`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: that’s the problem: “matches Foo and any subtype of Foo” means, the caller can substitute the type with a sub-type of Foo if (s)he wishes. In that case your returned `Function` had to return that sub-type of Foo but you can’t achieve that since the `Map`’s guaranty is to return Foo.

Comment: LOL We went different ways. You did a getter bound to the map where you pass in the key, and I did a getter bound to a key where you pass in the map. :-)

Answer (score 2):

My generics-fu is weak, but I think that would be:

```
public static <T, R> Function<T, R> foo() {
    // ...
}
```

But I don't think you can *instantiate* `R`, you'd have to be able to get it from `T`. Your code doesn't know the runtime type of `R`, so `new R()` is out of bounds.

But for example, if `T` can give you `R`, as with a `Map`:

```
public static <K, R, T extends Map<K,R>> Function<T, R> makeGetter(K key) {
    return a -> a.get(key);
}
```

That returns a getter that, when called with a given map, will return the entry with the key you used to create the getter:

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.*;
public class Example {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,Character> mapLower = new HashMap<String,Character>();
        mapLower.put("alpha", 'a');
        mapLower.put("beta",  'b');

        Map<String,Character> mapUpper = new HashMap<String,Character>();
        mapUpper.put("alpha", 'A');
        mapUpper.put("beta",  'B');

        Function<Map<String, Character>, Character> getAlpha = makeGetter("alpha");

        System.out.println("Lower: " + getAlpha.apply(mapLower));
        System.out.println("Upper: " + getAlpha.apply(mapUpper));
    }

    public static <K, R, T extends Map<K,R>> Function<T, R> makeGetter(K key) {
        return a -> a.get(key);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Lower: a
Upper: A
```

I don't think type erasure lets you get much closer than that, barring using an instance method and parameterizing your containing class.

Comment: I want the return type to be a subtype of the `Function`. Some own type like `A extends Function<In, Out>`, while I want to be able to put in every possible subtype of `Function` in the method `Foo`.